Why is "the paths" plural in Acts 2:28?
Acts 2:28 All quotes ESV

"You have made known to me the paths of life; you will make me full of gladness with your presence."

Here paths/hodous is plural.
Matthew 7:14

"For the gate is narrow and the way is hard that leads to life, and those who find it are few."

Here the way/hodos  is single.
John 14:6

"Jesus said to him, "I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me."

Here the way/hodos is single.
Why is "the paths" plural in Acts 2:28?

This is a quotation from Psalm 16:8-11. The NIV footnotes this and adds "See Septuagint". So I'm sure that will be part of the final answer.

Note that it says: “paths of life”! Not: “paths to life”. There is only one way to life, but there are many right choices for people on that one path, depending on circumstance.

Short Answer: In the original Hebrew text of Proverbs 5:6, the word for “path” is in the singular form. However, when this verse was translated into Greek in the Septuagint, the word became plural, “ὁδούς” (hodous).
LXX: Peter quotes from the LXX, which has the plural ὁδούς

Hebrew has the same word as here אֹ֣רַח in the singular


Some reasons for the plural might include:

Poetic language: Proverbs is known for its often use of metaphorical and symbolic language. The chosen translation for “paths of life” might be understood as the various ways that God reveals Himself to us in life.
Life’s many directions: The “paths” in Acts 2:28 could refer to life's many possible directions. Not that many paths lead to
eternal life. God's guidance is needed to find the right path.
Commandments of the Torah: In Jewish rabbinic literature, the “paths”
could refer to the different commandments or ways of the Torah. God
intentionally obscured the rewards for the commandments to prevent
people from favoring certain commandments over others based on the
perceived reward. [1]
Choices and consequences: Proverbs 5:6, deals
with the metaphorical “harlot”, the “paths” might have a different
connotation, perhaps related to the choices one makes in life and the
consequences of those choices. [1]


You could expand the answer by noting the Hebrew is ארח חיּים. Life is plural. Arguably the LXX plural paths makes better sense.

The use of the Greek word ὁδός (hodos) can be divided into four groups:

Literal and thus, "a way for travelling or moving from one place to another, way, road, highway", eg, Matt 2:12, 13:4, 15:32, 21:8, Mark 11:8, Luke 24:32, etc.
Literal and thus, "the action of travelling, way, trip, journey", eg, Matt 10:10, Mark 6:8, 10:17, Luke 9:3, Acts 1:12, etc.
Metaphoric generally and thus, "course of behavior, way of life, conduct", eg, Matt 7:13, 10:5, Acts 14:16, 22:4, Rom 3:16, James 1:8, etc.
Metaphoric specifically, technically and spiritually" and thus, "the whole way of life from a moral and spiritual viewpoint, the Way, teaching, method", eg, Matt 7:14, 21:32, Luke 3:4, 20:21, John 1:23, 14:4, 5, 6, Acts 2:28, 9:2, 13:10, 16:17, 18:25, 26, 19:9, 23, Rom 3:17, 11:33, 1 Cor 12:31, 1 Thess 3:11, Heb 9:8, 10:20, 2 Peter 2:2, 15, 21, Rev 15:3, etc.

Now, as the OP has already pointed out, this word, in its fourth meaning above can be either:

singular as per Matt 7:14, 21:32, 22;16, Luke 1:76, 3:4, 20:21, John 14:4, 5, 6, Acts 16:17, Heb 10:20, etc.
plural as per Luke 1:76, Acts 2:28 13:10, Rom 11:33, Heb 3:10, Rev 15:3

The distinction between these two appears to be rather simple:

Singular: appears to be Jesus as the way of salvation, the way of righteousness, the way of the Lord, the way of God, the path of peace, the way of love, the living way into the sanctuary, or just, "The Way", etc.
Plural: appears to be methods of God generally including the many ways God leads and draws people to the singular way of Jesus as the only way to know God.


The path metaphor was familiar to anybody in the Ancient World whose education had included Plato (who may have gotten it from the Psalms we don't know we can't tell etc):-
Plat. Meno 97a - - I will tell you. If a man knew the way to Larisa (τὴν ὁδὸν τὴν εἰς Λάρισαν), or any other place you please, and walked there and led others, would he not give right and good guidance?
This began a famous line of argument that concluded:-
Plat. Meno 100b - - Then the result of our reasoning, Meno, is found to be that virtue comes to us by a divine dispensation, when it does come.
Which tends to support John 14:6.

Acts 22:8 - - ἐγνώρισάς μοι ὁδοὺς ζωῆς - - the paths of life
Matthew 7:14 - - ἡ ὁδὸς ἡ ἀπάγουσα εἰς τὴν ζωήν - - the path leading to life
John 14:6 - - εἰμι ἡ ὁδὸς καὶ ἡ ἀλήθεια καὶ ἡ ζωή - - I am the path and the truth and the life

Acts 22:8 could be about life generally where not all the paths lead to the ζωὴν αἰώνιον of Matthew 7:14.
It's quoting Psalm 16:11, which has a singular path in the Hebrew that the LXX rendered as plural paths, probably because the moral life is conceived as a confusing map of many paths leading off in different directions, of which only one is right and we'll need God's help to identify it. Knowing where to find Larissa as well can't hurt.
It's a moot point whether the LXX were correct to do this, but God's paths are plural nearby in Psalm 25:4, so they don't have to conform to a later technical usage of ὁδὸς by the apostles. Or us.
Psalm 16, as many of the Psalms, is about the struggle with temptation in this life - whose path we'll need to lead around the other gods whose followers drink blood, and Sheol, and perhaps some traps and snares etc.
That doesn't restrict Psalm 16's path from being the singular one that leads to the presence of God and the τερπνότητες εἰς τέλος, but the point is that for the righteous God makes the two the same. And this singularity is brought out by the Psalm's poetry, not by moronic obedience to a singular/plural protocol. The emphasis is on the destination, not how special and pious we are for knowing it isn't a covenant of works.

Ps. 15:11

ἐγνώρισάς μοι ὁδοὺς ζωῆς πληρώσεις με εὐφροσύνης μετὰ τοῦ προσώπου σου τερπνότητες ἐν τῇ δεξιᾷ σου εἰς τέλος

Ps 15:11

"You have made known to me the paths of life; you will fill me with joy with your presence; pleasures are at your right hand forever."

Prov. 5:6

ὁδοὺς γὰρ ζωῆς οὐκ ἐπέρχεται σφαλεραὶ δὲ αἱ τροχιαὶ αὐτῆς καὶ οὐκ εὔγνωστοι

Prov 5:6

"For she does not go upon the paths of life; her ways are unstable, and they are not known."

Prov. 10:17

ὁδοὺς δικαίας ζωῆς φυλάσσει παιδεία παιδεία δὲ ἀνεξέλεγκτος πλανᾶται

Prov 10:17

"The instruction guards the righteous paths of life; but uncorrected instruction leads astray."

Prov. 12:28

ἐν ὁδοῖς δικαιοσύνης ζωή ὁδοὶ δὲ μνησικάκων εἰς θάνατον

Prov 12:28

"In the paths of righteousness is life; but the paths of those who bear grudges lead to death."

Prov. 15:24

ὁδοὶ ζωῆς διανοήματα συνετοῦ ἵνα ἐκκλίνας ἐκ τοῦ ᾅδου σωθῇ

Prov 15:24

"The paths of life are the thoughts of the wise, so that he may turn aside from Sheol and be saved."

In Acts 2:28, the author uses the plural "paths of life," following the Septuagint’s rendering, as found in Psalm 15:11 (LXX). The Septuagint often employs the plural form “ὁδοὺς ζωῆς” (paths of life) to convey the idea of multiple ways or aspects through which life or righteousness can be experienced, especially in relationship with God.
This choice is consistent with other uses in the Septuagint. In Psalm 15:11, it states, “You have made known to me the paths of life; you will fill me with joy with your presence; pleasures are at your right hand forever.” Here, "paths" emphasizes the variety and richness of ways through which God guides and fulfills the faithful.
Similarly, Proverbs 5:6 says, “For she does not go upon the paths of life; her ways are unstable, and they are not known.” Here, the plural "paths of life" again contrasts stability with errant ways, suggesting that there are various correct ways to live, which are disregarded by the unwise.
In Proverbs 10:17, “The instruction guards the righteous paths of life; but uncorrected instruction leads astray,” we see that "paths" pluralizes the routes of righteous living, guided by discipline and correction.
Likewise, Proverbs 12:28 states, “In the paths of righteousness is life; but the paths of those who bear grudges lead to death.” Here, “paths of righteousness” (plural) conveys that righteous living is multifaceted and stands in opposition to the multiple paths that lead to death.
Finally, Proverbs 15:24 uses “paths of life” in the plural: “The paths of life are the thoughts of the wise, so that he may turn aside from Sheol and be saved.” The use of “paths” reflects the breadth of understanding and options available to the wise, contrasting with those who lack discernment.
By adopting the plural "paths of life" in Acts 2:28, the author is aligning with the Septuagint tradition, emphasizing the idea of a divinely guided, multifaceted way of living that leads to joy, wisdom, and ultimately, life in God's presence.
